# QGIS Autofields expression function editor

Tags: qgis, autofields

I would like to have an Autofield that returns the length of a line segment plus 20. If that value is less than 150, I would like the Autofield to return 150. I am having trouble with syntax in the Function Editor for the Expression Builder for AutoFields. Below is my code:

```
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def BoreLength(geometry, feature, parent):
    layer=qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    length=geometry$length+20
    if length<150:
        length=150
        return length
    return length
```

And my Expression is currently this:
[image]

Comment: The screenshot looks like it's from QGIS 2, which is deprecated, rather than the current QGIS 3. There were some changes to pyqgis between the two versions, so please edit your question to indicate what version you're using.

Comment: `geometry$length` doesn't look correct to me. Should it be `geometry.$length` or possibly `length(geometry)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want your life to be easy and just want to get it to work, use the following expression.

```sql
max(length($geometry)+20, 150)
```

If you want to make things even easier, define it as *default value* for your field in vector layer properties --> fields and activate "apply on update", then you don't need a plugin.

If you want to learn about expression functions, you'll need to read the (more info) link and you will find some resources on the internet.

Comment: If @efrank is using AutoFields, then it's using QGIS v2.x. Still no *default value* functionality there. I'd suggest efrank to update to QGIS v3, and follow your recommendation on using *default values*.

Comment: Ended up using max($length+20,150) as my expression. Thanks for simplifying it! Correct, I am not using QGIS 3 yet.